# Pandas does not show first column

Tags: python, pandas, rename

I have a couple of function which filter a dataframe of different customers' features and return the filtered dataframe as below:

```
stg_1 = strategy_1_filtering(df_1)
stg_2 = strategy_2_filtering(df_2)
```

Now, I make an adjacency matrix to based on Customer IDs and strategies:

```
d = {'stg_1':stg_1['Customer_ID'],'stg_2':stg_2['Customer_ID']}
df  = pd.DataFrame({k: dict.fromkeys(v, True) for k, v in d.items()}).fillna(False)
```

And the result is something like this:

|  | stg_1 | stg_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 385986.0 | True | True |
| 363015.0 | True | False |
| 411847.0 | True | True |
| 413369.0 | True | True |
| 401081.0 | True | False |

I have tried to change the name of first column using this code:

```
 df.columns.values[0] = "Customer_ID"
```

But it did not work. To understand the problem I printed shape and column names of the dataframe:

```
print(df.shape)
print(df.columns)
```

The results:

```
(1155, 2)
Index(['stg_1', 'stg_2'], dtype='object')
```

In this case, when the dataframe cannot detect even the first column, what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your *first column* is actually the *index* of the DataFrame.
To name it:

```
df.index.name = "Customer_ID"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first column is actually an index. Use `rename_axis`:

```
df = df.rename_axis('Customer ID')
```

If you want the index as column, use `reset_index`:

```
df = df.rename_axis('Customer ID').reset_index()
```